# Why is Siri no longer searching Apple Music?

Tags: iphone, siri, apple-music

For over a week now when I ask Siri to play something it won’t search Apple Music and it will reply that couldn’t find it on my library. I tried restarting, removing and reinstalling the app, switching Siri off and on again but the issue persists. I even went as far as a factory reset. It started happening a few days after installing iOS 16.0.2
I am using an iPhone 12 Pro.
I have no issues with my iPad which always searches Apple Music, so does my MacBook and Apple Watch. On iPhone and CarPlay thing’s just don’t work. Something else I noticed is that when asking about the weather I don’t get the usual response. Siri responds with a web search.

Answer (score 0):

It started working today out of the blue.
I wouldn’t necessarily consider it fixed as there’s no apparent reason for starting to fail or starting to work again.